# Execute external SQL scripts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to build a sql script that I can break down into bite sized sections to make it easier to maintain however I'm struggling to get it working and using AI to help debug it isn't helping. I was wondering if anyone can drop me some insight why i cant simply execute a separate sql script?

```
-- Main SQL script for creating demo/test data
-- Prompt the user for clearing the database (Y/N)
DECLARE @ClearDatabaseOption CHAR(1)
SET @ClearDatabaseOption = 'Y' -- Change to 'Y' to clear the database

-- Check if the user wants to clear the database
IF @ClearDatabaseOption = 'Y'
BEGIN
    -- Execute a script to clear the database
    EXEC sp_executesql N':r PurchasingDataScripts\clear_database.sql';    
END
ELSE
BEGIN
-- Set up a transaction to ensure all or none of the changes are committed
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Step 1: Create default document type groups
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N':r PurchasingDataScripts\create_default_document_type_groups.sql';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 1: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 2: Create default document types
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_default_document_types.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 2: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 3: Create default document sequences
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_default_document_sequences.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 3: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 4: Create default profile
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_default_profile.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 4: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 5: Create Contacts
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_contacts.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 5: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 6: Create demo documents
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_demo_documents.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 6: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 7: Create demo people
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_demo_people.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 7: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 8: Create Purchasing Profile Finance Codes
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_purchasing_profile_finance_codes.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 8: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- Step 9: Create PurchasingEvents
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    :r PurchasingDataScripts\create_purchasing_events.sql
    ';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'Step 9: Error encountered. Rolling back changes.';
    RETURN;
END CATCH

-- If all steps completed successfully, commit the changes
COMMIT;
PRINT 'All steps completed successfully. Changes have been committed.';

-- End of the main script
```

Ive tried

```
DECLARE @CmdString NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @CmdString = 'sqlcmd -S server -d database -E -i "PurchasingDataScripts\clear_database.sql"';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @CmdString;

-- Disable xp_cmdshell for security (optional)
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: what's this `:r`thing? sp_executesql cannot execute external scripts, it looks like you're using the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: That's [sqlcmd utlity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-query-editor?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-sqlcmd-syntax) @siggemannen .

Comment: your second try is better, but you probably need to fully qualify the path to your script, and also it should be accessable to the sql server process. why not do this in a powershell OR even .bat script or something?

Comment: i was under the impression that :r can be used to include a script. Is it possible what im trying to do here?

Comment: You *appear* to be under the impression that passing a literal (to `sp_executesql`) will invoke a sqlcmd in the deferred statement; it will not.

Comment: what happened when you ran the xp_cmdshell thing? "i've tried" doesn't say if you succeeded nor what error you got

Comment: If you just want to execute the contents of a file, using sqlcmd, in SSMS, you just need to do `:r <File path>`

Comment: For [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBlmN.png). This looks more like the AI sent you down a rabbit hole (there's a reason I call it CrapGPT). Just reference the file, you don't need any of that `sp_executesql` stuff. Seems like a typographical error at best to me.

Comment: honestly you are not wrong, i know executing scripts is possible in sql but never needed to do it so gave it a go, ive executed stored procedures etc with sql in the past so partially tried myself and yes used AI. I have found AI can be a good tool if you roughly know what is right and wrong but in this case i was shooting in the air. I have written it up as a powershell script instead which works.